# Laravel 5.2 & Dingo api.auth middleware group

Tags: php, laravel, dingo-api

I try to GET result of "testing" from the API with Authorization as header but I don't know why it doesn't work. It works for "hello" but not works for "testing". It doesn't produce any error and it redirect me to the main page of Laravel.

AuthController.php

```
public function show()
{
    return "testing";
}
```

Routes.php

```
$api = app('api.router');
$api->version('v1', ['middleware' => 'api.auth'], function($api){
    $api->get('show','App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@show');//not working
    $api->get('hello',function(){
        return "hello"; //works
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AuthController has a __construct that it use guest middleware, so if you are login in the system it will be redirect you to $redirectTo route.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, this really help me a lots

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by moving the function from AuthController to ExampleController.

```
$api = app('api.router');
$api->version('v1', ['middleware' => 'api.auth'], function($api){
    $api->get('show','App\Http\Controllers\ExampleController@show');
    $api->get('hello',function(){
        return "hello"; 
    });
});
```